# How to load API result in Bootstrap Modal using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I'm trying to open a Bootstrap Modal in my webapp which I build with Backbone.js. To do this I use this [backbone.bootstrap-modal](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone.bootstrap-modal) from github. This works easily when loading a simple modal:

```
var ListUsersModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html($('#my-modal-template').html());
        return this;
    }
});
```

which I show using this code:

```
new Backbone.BootstrapModal({
    animate: true,
    content: new ListUsersModalView()
}).open();
```

I now try to load a list of models from an API call into the model. I now have the following code:

```
var ListSupportersModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#div-for-list-of-names',
    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        var users = new UserCollection();
        users.fetch({
            success: function() {
                var template = _.template($('#my-modal-template').html(), {users: users.models});
                that.$el.html(template);
                return that;
            }
        });
    }
    return that;
});
```

This doesn't work and I understand why; I need to return `this` including the loaded collection. Unfortunately the users are fetched asynchronously and therefore the last `return that;` doesn't include the usermodels.

The question is now; how can I solve this? How can I load the models from the API call into the modal? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery's deferred object would be the best way to go about this in my opinion.

This can allow you to return a "promise" that you will handle later on in your code. Once you either resolve or reject the promise you can then handle displaying the data or showing an error if you rejected it. (more can be read about it here http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

a quick example of how you could restructure to make use of this

```
var ListSupportersModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    users: null,

    // This tells the view which element is its container
    // remove this if you don't need it.
    el: '#div',

    initialize: function() {
        this.users = new UserCollection();
    },

    //moved this to a it's own function so that it can 
    //return the promise for action it is completing
    getUsers: function() {
        var defer = $.Deferred();
        this.users.fetch({
            success: function() {
                //users should now be a full collection so
                //resolve the promise
                defer.resolve();
            },
            error: function() {
                //users fetch failed so reject the promise
                defer.reject();
            }
        });

        //return the promise from the deferred object
        var promise = defer.promise();
        return promise;


    },
    render: function() {

        var template = _.template($('#my-modal-template').html(), {
            users: this.users.models
        });
        this.$el.html(template);

        return this;
    }

});
```

Then when setting up the bootstrap modal

```
var listUsersModalView = new ListUsersModalView();

//get the users and this will return the prmoise;
var listUsersModalViewPromise = listUsersModalView.getUsers();


//set up listen for when the promise is resolved/rejected
$.when(listUsersModalViewPromise).done(function() {


    //only change i have made is to pass the listUserModalView that has already
    //been initialized as this will now have a fetched user collection
    new Backbone.BootstrapModal({
        animate: true,
        content: listUsersModalView
    }).open();
}).fail(function() {
    //do something here to show that an error occured?
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I implemented your answer. It all seems to work ALMOST. It gets the models alright, and opens the modal. It just doesn't show anything in the modal. I inserted some manual html behine `content:` which works. I did a `console.log(listUsersModalView)` just before I run `new Backbone.BootstrapModal(etc..` and it includes the usermodels. The only thing it doesn't do is display the content. Don't I need to convert it to html somehow? I'm desperate since I'm so close to the solution now! One last tip is very very welcome!

Comment: Nevermind! Solved it! I also had to remove `el: '#div-for-list-of-names',`. All is well now! Thanks a million!

Comment: Ah yeah sorry I just copied you example for the bulk of the code in my example. Glad you fixed it.